# Sleuth in Webflux Spring Security

Tags: filter, spring-security, spring-cloud-sleuth, webflux

I have a webflux app and need to have sleuth context in my authentication logs (move from DefaultWebFilterChain to SecurityWebFilterChain).

I have tried to add manually in my security chain:

```
public GwApiSecurityConfig(Tracer tracer, HttpServerHandler httpServerHandler, CurrentTraceContext currentTraceContext){
    this.tracer = tracer;
    this.httpServerHandler = httpServerHandler;
    this.currentTraceContext = currentTraceContext;
}

@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/swagger", "/v3/**", "/webjars/**", "/actuator/**").permitAll()
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint((exchange, exception) -> Mono.error(new GwException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, GwError.AUTHENTICATION)))
            .and()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .redirectToHttps()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(new TraceWebFilter(tracer, httpServerHandler, currentTraceContext), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.HTTP_BASIC)
            .build();
}
```

But I got an error:

```
    09:11:06.117 ERROR[reactor-http-nio-2] [,] GwApiErrorHandler - null
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceWebFilter.spanFromContextRetriever(TraceWebFilter.java:139)
```

Also I checked this property:

```
spring.sleuth.web.filter-order=1
```

but I think that only affect the DefaultWebFilterChain order, no SecurityWebFilterChain.
And how to remove the filter from DefaultWebFilterChain to avoid filtering twice?

Any ideas?
Thanks!